# Disallow branches off of branch?

Tags: git

We've got three branches -- Master, Dev, and Test. All features get branched from Master to correspond with Jira tickets, allowing them to be easily merged one-by-one to Dev and Test. However, we just ran into an issue on Test where a merged feature caused a bunch of issues. It turns out that that feature branch was actually created off of Dev instead of Master.  Obviously a better review process would have caught this (and it's great that we caught it before it made its way to Master), but ideally this case shouldn't even be possible.

Is it possible to set up something like a protected branch, but that only allows merging and not branching? That way we are only able to branch off of Master, but *not* off of Test or Dev?

Comment: Git itself does not have something like that, although you could implement it using Git hooks. But you should probably do this on your CI instead, as an automated process as part of your reviews. How to do that depends on your system but maybe you can find an easy way to implement that (e.g. on GitHub you could create a web hook that verifies this)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider keeping some of the branches on a separate repo so that devs don't have access to them?

Comment: @poke https://githooks.com/ seems to imply that there are no hooks relating to branching, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Mrweiner You wouldn’t restrict branching because that would directly impact the productivity of the developers, but you would probably restrict pushing instead. So your rule would be “don’t push a feature branch that wasn’t based off master”

Answer (score 1):

You could handle this during merge, by not allowing a merge to happen if any of the commit ids returned by `git log Master..Dev` is found in `feature-branch` using something like `git branch --contains=...`

I believe this will take a bit of scripting and finding the right hooks for your process, but it's possible to get to a solution that brings more safety to your deployments.